# How to update 2 SQL table and deduct values from the given action

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Need your help with my Code.
The page is for approving the `"leave application"`
For example, the employee applied for `"Sick Leave"` and It is approved it will deduct 1 from the `sl_credit` which is from the user_info table on my database and will also update the remarks, remarkable, and status to the `tblleaves table`.
I am getting an error message "error updating table"

On my code, I just tried the "Approved" to test if it is working.

I hope someone could help me with this. I'm very new to programming and would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php

$uid = $_GET['ref'];

$leavetype = $_GET['leavetype'];
$adminremark = $_POST['adminremark'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$adminremarkdate = $_POST['adminremarkdate'];
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


include '../db_config/connection.php';

if ($leavetype == "Sick Leave" || $status == "Approved") {

$sql = "UPDATE tblleaves, user_info SET adminremark='$adminremark', status='$status', adminremarkdate = '$date', user_info.sl_credit=user_info.sl_credit-1, WHERE id='$uid'";

}elseif ($leavetype == "Vacation Leave" || $status == "Approved") {
    $sql = "UPDATE tblleaves, user_info SET adminremark='$adminremark', status='$status', adminremarkdate = '$date', user_info.vl_credit=user_info.vl_credit-1, WHERE id='$uid'";
}


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("location:leave-details.php?ref=$uid");
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: You can't do an Update of two tables at the same time like that `update table1, table2` that is incorrect, just one table.

Comment: @Paplusc : Yes, actually, you can...  MySQL has syntax for exactly that.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d85e9/1

Comment: @MatBailie Cool, i didn't know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the whole error message, you're just telling us the error message that you coded in to your `echo`...

As for people saying you can't update two tables at once, normally that's true, but in MySQL you ***can***:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d85e9/1

The three problems I can see are...

You have an extra `,` just before your `WHERE` clause, remove it...

```
user_info.sl_credit=user_info.sl_credit-1, WHERE id='$uid'
                                         ^
```

The `WHERE` clause needs to reference both tables being updated...

```
WHERE user_info.id = '$uid' AND tblleaves.user_id = user_info.id
```

*(Or similar)*

Also, you have `SET adminremark='$adminremark',` but ***every*** column being updated should specify the table as well...

```
SET tblleaves.adminremark='$adminremark', etc, etc

OR

SET user_info.adminremark='$adminremark', etc, etc
```

Comment: Hi MatBailie. Yes. That's the error message I set up. meaning to say that my code is not working.

I will try that.

Comment: @jackflick - And so, by telling us the error message ***you*** wrote, you've hidden the full error message from MySQL.  It's nice to know that it's not working, and my answer shows two reasons why.  But you should include the ***full and complete*** error message from MySQL.

Comment: Hi Mat. It did work. but it deducts 1 to every employee I have on the table.

Comment: Here's the code. `$sql = "UPDATE tblleaves, user_info SET tblleaves.adminremark='$adminremark', tblleaves.status='$status', tblleaves.adminremarkdate = '$date', user_info.sl_credit = user_info.sl_credit - 1 WHERE id='$uid'";`

Comment: @jackflick see my edited answer. Your where clause is insufficient

Comment: It worked Mat. now I need help in setting up the if it is "sick leave" or "vacation leave" it will deduct and only if the leave status is approve.

Comment: That's a different question. You should isolate your problem and create a new question about that specific scenario.